# Unknown symbol when loading a kernel module but the symbol is exported in kernel

Tags: linux, kernel-module

I am writing a kernel module to manipute GPIOs. In initialization, the moduel needs to change the muplex of GPIOs.

[tld.c]

```
#include <mach-omap2/mux.h>
```

.
.
.

```
int open_gpio(void){
    int result;
    result = gpio_request_array(leds_gpios, ARRAY_SIZE(leds_gpios));
    if(result != 0) {
        printk("tld: cannot request gpio ports\n");
    }

    result = gpio_direction_output(LED_LE_PIN, 0);

    omap_mux_set_gpio(OMAP_MUX_MODE7, LED_LE_PIN);
    if(result != 0) {
        printk("tld: cannot change GPIO muplex.\n");
        gpio_free_array(leds_gpios, ARRAY_SIZE(leds_gpios));
    }
    return result;
} 

static int tld_init(void) { 
        .
        .
    /* open gpio ports */
    result = open_gpio();
        .
        .
}
    .
module_init(tld_init);
    .
```

Function omap_mux_set_gpio() is declared in Kernel_Source/arch/arm/mach-omap2/mux.h. So I include it in the source file.

The Makefile is also customized.

[Makefile]

```
CONFIG_CROSS_COMPILE =
CROSS_COMPILE ?= $(CONFIG_CROSS_COMPILE:"%"=%)

ARCH        ?= arm

SOURCE_DIR ?= /home/me/kerner_source

AS      = $(CROSS_COMPILE)as
LD      = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ld
CC      = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
CPP     = $(CC) -E
AR      = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ar
NM      = $(CROSS_COMPILE)nm
STRIP       = $(CROSS_COMPILE)strip
OBJCOPY     = $(CROSS_COMPILE)objcopy
OBJDUMP     = $(CROSS_COMPILE)objdump

obj-m += tld.o
ccflags-y += -I$(SOURCE_DIR)/arch/arm


all:
make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C $(SOURCE_DIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
rm *.o *.ko *.mod.*
```

I can get it compiled but there is warning:

**WARNING: "omap_mux_set_gpio" [/home/me/projects/tld.ko] undefined!**

When i run insmod, there is error in dmesg:

**tld: Unknown symbol omap_mux_set_gpio (err 0)**

I have checked the kernel symbol list by runing:

cat /proc/kallsyms | grep omap_mux_set_gpio

An function called omap_mux_set_gpio does exist.

I think the way I include the header file probably is causing the problem. The mux.h belongs to the kernel itself but i treat it like an external one.

What is right way to do it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If a symbol is not marked as `EXPORT_SYMBOL` or `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL`, then you can not use it in kernel modules. This symbol does not appear to be marked in that way.

Comment: sharth: I do a search and it seems that omap_mux_set_gpio is not marked as EXPORT_SYMBOL. But it appears in the kernel symbol list. If that is the reason. What can I do about it?

Comment: @yiqi: In my experience, You would need to get EXPORT_SYMBOL applied to that symbol in the .c file that is built into the kernel.